# Retain JSON data after get request in Typescript

Tags: javascript, json, http, typescript, get

I'am trying to call a REST api from a distant server to retrieve some usefull data. This data is meant to be injected in a Angular2 LineChart.

I manage to retrieve the Json file and cast it to a custom Interface.

My interface generated by Json2ts.com

[image: My interface generated by Json2ts.com]

Here is my Constructor and LineChart Variables to fill with the Json Data. 
In the constructor i cast the json result in my Interface Type: RootObject When printing the json value in console the value is Valid.

[image: Here is my Constructor and LineChart Variables to fill with get request Json Data. When printing the json value in console the value is valid]

I also can t assign value from the data i gather from the JSon File or i get an error of type : Cannot read property 'linechart' of undefined

[image: I also can t assign value from the data i gather from the JSon File]

The problem is that i can't set an class data variable from the constructor, or directly set the data to the chart. Is their a way to set

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try async

```
var me = this;

this.http.get('url').map((res:any)=>{ 
let data = .....
me.data = data })
return me.data;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!